# How does the bank in Game of Thrones / A Song of Ice and Fire work?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

How does the bank in Game of Thrones / ASOIF work? Withdrawing, depositing, etc.

As people can't always carry around their winnings, how do they withdraw and deposit money?

Comment: I guess like a normal bank

Comment: Hi ty for reply. What do you mean? They didn't have cards and what if they went to a bank in another city?

Comment: @LiamBrown There were banks before there were cards and electronics. If you're wondering about banking history, this is the wrong place to be.

Comment: Im not. in the show/ books they can win 10,000 upwards inn tournaments. if they deposit it how do they withdraw it

Comment: @LiamBrown the same way people did in the Middle Ages. People then used to have huge winnings.

Comment: Yes but how did they do that Shevliaskovic

Comment: Did they have a book or something

Comment: @LiamBrown You are clearly asking about banking history. That was a rhetorical question. Yes, they used ledgers and whatnot. How else? This is not explained in ASOIAF.

Comment: TLP so where can I read about the ledgers then? Also you don't have to be rude i was just confused how they go to a different city and can get money.

Comment: wiki says "That being said, sometimes possession is an abstract concept. Thus someone being paid thousands of Gold Dragon coins will not have to physically carry them around, but will be presented with official financial documents declaring the transaction (much as a knight might find it difficult to carry around on his back a castle he has been granted, but can carry around a sealed charter as proof of the land grant)." Does that mean they show teller they have the amount in account and they can withdraw?

Comment: The bank is actually an invention of the Knight Templars (no, this is not a conspiracy theory). They managed to control various places in Holy Land, so a pilgrim could travel there with no money (less attacks from bandits) and use instead an encoded bill of exchange (Templars knew their cryptography...). [See this for further research](http://books.google.com/books?id=8UBDndXgNIYC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=bill+of+exchange+templars&source=bl&ots=5S1Qo453lf&sig=pLLFUKZaDbVLEg8c9kMxwhf-FZg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=12xOVPWEBs_9yQT4wYCYDg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bill%20of%20exchange%20templars&f=false)

Comment: @LiamBrown: Hi and welcome to StackExchange. Etiquette here is to only ask questions which **cannot** easily be answered by standard reference sources or use of Google. As other commenters have indicated, you are effectively asking, "how did banking work before modern communications?" This is (a) easily answered by Googling "history of banking", and (b) off-topic for SF & Fantasy SE (just like a generic question about historical sword-making or agriculture would be).

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit I think there's a distinct difference between asking "How did banking work during the Middle Ages?" and asking "How does banking work in the world of A Song of Ice and Fire?" and the answer (potentially) being that it's the same as banking in the middle ages.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Agreed, but as other commenters have said, the answer is basically "GRRM doesn't say how it works, but we can assume it is similar to historical methods."

Comment: Since your name suggests that English is your first language - could you please use that knowledge to make your question readable? This is not Twitter, you know.
If it's not your first language, I strongly suggest [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't think there are details, but from the TV show I get the impression that the Iron Bank is supposed to be an imposing institution that is the shadow of power for the so-called powerful kings and lords. They don't give much details yet, but a great documentary on the history of banking is 'The Money Masters' which can be found on YouTube. Try this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrJGlXEs8nI

Answer (score 10):

The only bank we read about in the books is the Iron Bank of Braavos, which doesn't actually serve the common Westerosi. This doesn't however mean that there are no similar (though smaller) institutions elsewhere. However, since we have yet to come across any of them, then we can safely assume that once again they are not something the average Westerosi has access to.

Westeros is still a cash only society. Yes, you *are* expected to lug around all those gold dragons you won in the tourney with you. That's why we see wealthy merchants hire mercenaries and hedge knights to protect them (and by extension their money). Characters are often seen hiding their coins in inventive way to avoid losing it to a bandit.